# knitr tables appear as one long column

Tags: r, knitr

I pretty much copied word-for-word the example from this site on how to create multiple PDFs in knitr from one for-loop: http://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/software/R/markdown_multiple_reports.html

When I try calling `knitr::kable(cars)` or `kable(cars)` the output of each PDF appears as one long column instead of an actual table, as shown in the photo.

[image]

Any idea what causes this? Here's the .R and the .Rmd code called in each iteration of the loop:

**.R**

```
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown)
mt <- mtcars[1:5,]
for (car in unique(rownames(mt))){
     rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',
                output_format = "pdf_document",
                output_file =  paste(car, ' report.pdf', sep=''), 
                output_dir = '~/')
```

**test.Rmd**

```
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown)
cars <- mtcars[rownames(mtcars)==car,]

# create example data 
x <- sample(1:10, 1)
cars <- do.call("rbind", replicate(x, cars, simplify = FALSE))

# create hypothetical lat and lon data 
cars$lat <- sapply(rownames(cars), function(x) round(runif(1, 30, 46), 3))
cars$lon <- sapply(rownames(cars), function(x) round(runif(1, -115, -80),3))
knitr::kable(cars)
kable(cars)
```

I was able to get are relatively normal looking table by using `kable(cars, format = "latex")`

[image]

I was hoping to get some quick and decent html tables, and now when I try to format in LaTeX with something like `kable(cars, format = "latex", booktabs = T)`, I get this error:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like? It's unclear exactly what you are trying to do with `cars$lat <- sapply(rownames(cars), function(x) round(runif(1, 30, 46), 3))`. Are you just trying to round one columns? Are you trying to store multiple columns in the `lat` column of `cars`?

Comment: @MrFlick I added an edit to show the kind of table it should look like. Re: $lat and $lon: They're just some random extra columns to add on. The example in the site includes some map data too, but I was just testing the ability to create multiple PDFs  with one for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the .Rmd file to include the package in output
Create a YAML header with

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{booktabs}
```

modified .Rmd file which now works for me (I was also reproducing your error)

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{booktabs}
output:
    pdf_document
---
```{r kable}
library(knitr) 
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown) 
cars <-mtcars[rownames(mtcars)==car,]

# create example data 
x <- sample(1:10, 1) 
cars <- do.call("rbind", replicate(x, cars, simplify =FALSE))

# create hypothetical lat and lon data 
cars$lat <- sapply(rownames(cars), function(x) round(runif(1, 30, 46), 3))
cars$lon <-sapply(rownames(cars), function(x) round(runif(1, -115, -80),3))
knitr::kable(cars, format = "latex", booktabs = T)
```
````

Now this produces four files

[image]

Comment: That does not help me, who has the exact same problem only knittering for word instead

Comment: Some issues related to rmarkdown and tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704329/how-to-format-kable-table-when-knit-from-rmd-to-word-with-bookdown/47739242#47739242