# How to format kable table when knit from .rmd to Word (with bookdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, kableextra

I have read the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) and still cannot figure this out. I am trying to create a Word report through `bookdown`.  I want to use `kableExtra` to add striping to my tables and also to bold my last table row. Can `kableExtra` be used when knitting to Word ?

This is a subset of my code :

```
library(dplyr)    
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)  # required for kable
library(kableExtra)  # required for kableExtra
options(knit.r.table.format = "markdown")

myRegion <- c("a", "b", "c")
Current_Perc_1 <- c(85.9, 90.8, 89.7)
Current_Perc_2 <- c(88.0, 91.0, 89.0)
tab_curr_est_2_times <- cbind(myRegion, Current_Perc_1, Current_Perc_2)
tab_curr_est_2_times <- as.data.frame(tab_curr_est_2_times, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tab_curr_est_2_times$Current_Perc_1 <- as.double(tab_curr_est_2_times$Current_Perc_1)
tab_curr_est_2_times$Current_Perc_2 <- as.double(tab_curr_est_2_times$Current_Perc_2)
tab_curr_est_2_times$curr_change_1_to_2 <- tab_curr_est_2_times$Current_Perc_2 - tab_curr_est_2_times$Current_Perc_1

tab_1_curr <- tab_curr_est_2_times
tab_1_curr[ nrow(tab_1_curr)+1 , ] <- NA
tab_1_curr$myRegion[ nrow(tab_1_curr) ] <- "BRITISH COLUMBIA"
tab_1_curr$Current_Perc_1[ nrow(tab_1_curr) ] <- 88.4
tab_1_curr$Current_Perc_2[ nrow(tab_1_curr) ] <- 89.3
tab_1_curr$curr_change_1_to_2[ nrow(tab_1_curr) ] <- 0.9

knitr::kable(tab_1_curr, digits = 1, align = "lccc", position = "c", 
         caption = "\\: my table caption here") %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>%
  row_spec(nrow(tab_1_curr), bold = TRUE)
```

My bookdown settings are as follows:

```
--- 
title: "My Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: "bookdown::bookdown_site"
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    fig_caption: true
documentclass: book
---
```

When I click on the Knit button in RStudio, I get this table:

[image]

I want the last row to be bold and I want the table striped. How do I do this ? (I also get the following error: "Currently generic markdown table using pandoc is not supported.")

Comment: If you want to create a report in *Word*, you should read about the [`officer`](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/) package. The `kableExtra` package provides fine control for `html` and `latex` tables only.

Comment: Thank you @KevinArseneau. I will check out `officer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pandoc version ≥2

Yes, this can be done with Pandoc (see [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777330/5432121))

Original answer follows:

## Pandoc version <2

The conversion to word is made via `pandoc`. Currently pandoc only creates four type of tables,

- simple tables
- multiline_tables
- grid_tables
- pipe_tables

Some of those supported formats are demontrated in [pander](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/vignettes/pandoc_table.html) and in the [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/README.pdf) p 35-39.

So you **cannot** create the **stripped table** currently with pandoc.

You also have a good summary of how you can use tables in [rmarkdown.rstudio](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html).

Comment: It is very refreshing to hear that it is NOT possible to knit to Word doc and use `kableExtra`. This has not been clear to me anywhere, so I appreciate it. Hopefully this will save someone hours/days of time in the future!

Answer (score 19):

This was not possible but since pandoc V2 is out, you can do it with package `flextable (>= 0.4.0)`(and **pandoc V2**). Below the code you should add into a code chunk:

```
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)

tab_1_curr <- structure(list(myRegion = c("a", "b", "c", "BRITISH COLUMBIA"
 ), Current_Perc_1 = c(85.9, 90.8, 89.7, 88.4), Current_Perc_2 = c(88, 
 91, 89, 89.3), curr_change_1_to_2 = c(2.09999999999999, 0.200000000000003, 
 -0.700000000000003, 0.9)), .Names = c("myRegion", "Current_Perc_1", 
 "Current_Perc_2", "curr_change_1_to_2"), row.names = c(NA, 4L
 ), class = "data.frame")


flextable(tab_1_curr) %>% 
  bold(i = ~ myRegion %in% "BRITISH COLUMBIA") %>% 
  theme_zebra() %>% 
  autofit()
```

Comment: Thank you! `flextable` just saved my life.

Answer (score 9):

The `huxtable` package is available. It includes similar table customization tools as `kableExtra`. `huxtable` is designed to output to LaTeX/PDF and HTML (similar to `kableExtra`). However, `huxtable` also includes a `as_flextable` function to convert a huxtable object to a flextable object, which can be output to Word (as noted by David above). After a lot of searching, it seems to me like `huxtable` is the only available package that can easily output to all of Word, HTML, and PDF with a single package.