# RMarkdown - word output - hot to display tables correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I'm creating documentation using rmarkdown and Word as output.
I'm not able to display correctly tables created using knitr/kable.
They are displayed as plain text not table.

RMarkdown code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Supek"
date: "9/9/2019"
output: word_document
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
data(mtcars)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

kable(dt) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed"))
````

Comment: You can output a basic table to Word with `kable(dt, format="markdown")`, but see @novica's answer for other options for more flexable table output in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://community.rstudio.com/t/nice-tables-when-knitting-to-word/3840) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704329/how-to-format-kable-table-when-knit-from-rmd-to-word-with-bookdown) seem to suggest using another R package for getting tables in MSWord.

Comment: You're right. I have used wrong library. According to this: https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/design-principles.html only huxtable and flextable works with Word output.